# how to remove attribute from div using css in wordpress cms

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I use wordpress cms for an e-commerce site, on my shop page pagination is  not displayed and when I inspect element I see this

```
<div class="shop-loop-after clearfix" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
```

in inspection when I remove `display:none` from style attribute it work

I also tried this on shop page but it does not work

```
document.getElementByClassName('shop-loop-after').removeAttr('style')

<div class="shop-loop-after clearfix" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
```

I want to how to remove the display attribute using css

Comment: You surely can do it with a simple line of CSS like, `.shop-loop-after { display: block !important; }`

Comment: Or if you want to implement this with js you should get the first child of `document.getElementByClassName` like this:
`document.getElementByClassName('shop-loop-after')[0].removeAttribute('style')`

Answer (score 2):

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div>
```

With JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

With CSS:

```
.item{
    display: inherit !important;
}
```

Examples:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

```css
.item{
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     border: solid gray 3px;
     display: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div>
```